# Output an array with flask

Tags: python, flask

I need some help with a code.
I'm using flask framework for the firs time and recently did a hello world.
But what I need to do, is the following:

```
GET localhost/
return hello world ---> Done

POST localhost/4
return [0 1 2 3 4] ---> not yet
```

The logic is simple and I've done it already, but I don't know how to post it in the web application

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're trying to accept an array as input or you're trying to return an array?

Comment: I´m trying to return an array. For example when I wrtite http://localhos/4, the web application should show something like this : 0, 1, 2, 3, 4

Comment: @Cfreak looks like he's trying to get the app to return `range(n+1)` for any POST request to an endpoint `n`

Comment: Generally you want to have a template and then use that to output a list in a loop. I guess you turn it to JSON or something if you are using the output inside of javascript.  I think we need more info on what you're trying to accomplish

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried something like this:

```
@app.route('/<num:int>', methods=["POST"])
def range_up_to(num):
    return jsonify(range(num))
```

This sets the route to `/<some integer>` with the POST method to the `range_up_to` handler.  The value of `num` is passed as an argument.  `jsonify` is part of the `flask` package.  (`from flask import jsonify`) or (`import flask` ... `return flask.jsonify(range(num))`)

Comment: I need somethin like that, I'll try it. Thanks :)

Comment: As @AdamSmith mentioned you might want to make this `range(num + 1)` if the idea is for a request to `/4` to give back `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` or similar.

Comment: the python code for that would be ´number = 4
array =[]

def funct(number):
    for i in range (0,number+1):
        array.append(i)
        
    print array

funct(number)´

Comment: I tried with jsonify, but didnt work :/ It says Methos not allowed

Answer (score 0):

jsonify cannot convert an iterator. You must run through all values first.
Based on sberry answer, you can use:

```
@app.route('/<num>', methods=["POST"])
def range_up_to(num):
    return jsonify([x for x in range(int(num))])
```